# How to get co-ordinates of line with the help of OpenCv in android

Tags: java, android, opencv, hough-transform

[image]
I want to co-ordinates of lines with the help of OpenCV in android. I studied the tutorial and this is what my api call is

```
Mat ImageMat = new Mat(croppedImage.getHeight(), croppedImage.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8U, new Scalar(4));
int threshold = 50;
int minLineSize = 100;
int lineGap = 20;

Mat lines = new Mat();
Imgproc.HoughLinesP(ImageMat, lines, 1, Math.PI / 180, threshold, minLineSize, lineGap);
```

I provide a simple image with one line in it but in "lines" variable I get hundreds of co-ordinates. I just one co-ordinate of that single line. How to get co-ordinate of that single line only. Also what is the unit in which minLineSize is measured? My lines are the lines which are in front of FirstName, LastName etc.

Comment: Probably your line is too thick so you'll find plenty of 1-width lines in your thick line. please post your origibal image and if possible an image with all detected lines drawn.

Comment: minLineSize should be measured in pixel distance (probably euclidean or approx of euclidean)

Comment: @Micka The image is in the question now

Comment: You want to detect the black lines? Youll have to convert to grayscale first and threshold < small value so that the lines will be shown as white pixel in a black&white mask.

Comment: @Micka Please tell the steps. I am not able to get.

Comment: Sorry cant code in Android OpenCV but I'll try to write a c++ answer later.

Comment: I am using HoughLinesP with Ruby ropencv FFI interface it accepts Lines as Mat lines can anyone tell me how can I translate into Vector of Vec4i.

Answer (score 0):

Here's code in C++. Since mostly OpenCV functions are used, you might be able to port it do android CV easily:

```
int main()
{
    // loading your image. you dont need theses parts
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("../inputData/FormularLineDetection.png");


    // convert to grayscale: you will do something similar:
    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::cvtColor(input, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    // computation of binary thresholding so that dark areas of the image will bevcome "foreground pixel".
    // If your image have bright features you'll have to choose different parameters.
    // If you want to detect contour lines instead you'll compute gradient magnitude first.
    cv::Mat mask;
    cv::threshold(gray, mask, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV | CV_THRESH_OTSU);

    std::vector<cv::Vec4i> lines;
    //cv::HoughLinesP(mask, lines, 1, CV_PI/180.0, 50, 50, 10 );
    // I've changed the min-Size of a line to 1/3 of the images width. Maybe you'll have to adjust that parameter to your needs!
    cv::HoughLinesP(mask, lines, 1, CV_PI/180.0, 50, input.cols/3, 10 );



    // draw the lines to visualize: you might not do this at all
    for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
    {
        cv::Vec4i l = lines[i];
        cv::line( input, cv::Point(l[0], l[1]), cv::Point(l[2], l[3]), cv::Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);
    }

    // display and save to disk
    cv::imshow("mask", mask);   // you might not want to display the image here.
    cv::imshow("output",input);
    cv::imwrite("../outputData/FormularLineDetection.png", input);

    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

with your input I get this output:

[image]

as you can see, your desired lines are detected, but in addition that big thick "line" is detected too. You might want to try to detect structures like that and filter them out!